# Data/Web Scraping: Modify results per page

Tags: vbscript, web-scraping

Is it possible to manipulate "results returned per page" outside of the given selectable boundaries?

For example, this link:

http://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/Beverly+Hills+CA-90210?zip=90210&showcaseOwnerId=68687451&startYear=1981&numRecords=100&firstRecord=0&endYear=2017&searchRadius=50

I can manually change `numRecords` (`numRecords=100`) in the URL to any number that's selectable in the dropdown, but anything other than those preset choices have no impact.

Is there a way to make it have an impact?  I'm trying to display every result on a single page so when I do data scraping, I only have to scrape a single page and don't have to programmatically navigate many pages.  Is this possible?

Comment: I am afraid this is totally site-dependent, it totally depends on the functionality that they created

Comment: Makes sense, but figured it was worth asking.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, No;

This page receive the number of car to display in the GET request (hence the `&numRecords=100` in there [url](http://www.autotrader.com/cars-for-sale/Beverly+Hills+CA-90210?zip=90210&showcaseOwnerId=68687451&startYear=1981&numRecords=100&firstRecord=0&endYear=2017&searchRadius=50)).

I've tried to send other value than the 4 dropdown options, but it sames that every thing beside the predefined choice is ignored by the server side. so I guess you have need to send a GET request by each page.

To do so, just increment `&firstRecord` by 100 for each request until you reach the last page.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm familiar with programmatically navigating pages....all too familiar.  haha

Comment: you're welcome, it would be great if it was possible to get all the data in one go though :)